# Why are there no car packs in my garage?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

I purchased the *Forza Horizon 2 Ultimate - Anniversary Edition* download for Xbox one. I do not see any car packs in my garage.

How do I access my purchased cars?

Comment: To clarify for OP and the editor, I flagged this question as unclear because we require a question be more direct then "can somebody help?".

Comment: Where are the cars that I purchased in Forza Horizon 2  "Ultimate - Anniversary Edition?"

Comment: please note that when we ask questions to help us understand the question, you should address them as an edit to your actual question. I have edited your question, but am still unsure if you are having trouble viewing **all** cars, or just DLC cars (ie. Do you mean cars you purchase in game, or cars you purchase with real money).

Comment: @Timelord64 instead of voting to close, ask for clarification, etc. Try to help the poster - especially if they are new here. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to make sure to go to each car pack in the Xbox Store (go to the main Forza Horizon 2 store page then 'Add-Ons' -> 'See all add-ons' and click Install for each car pack.